# I want to keep a column in getSymbols or get.hist.quote with the Date as as.Date format

Tags: r, quantmod

I use `getSymbols` to download historical information over an environment with 200 tickers but I cannot seem to keep the date information from becoming an index.  I tried to specify `return.class` to `"ts"` and `"zoo"` also but no luck...

I also used `get.hist.quote` with similar success...

BUT the only thing that works is

```
xom <- read.csv("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=xom&a=11&b=31&c=2012", stringsAsFactors=F)


# The first column contains dates.  The as.Date
# function can convert strings into Date objects.
#
    xom_dates <- as.Date(xom[,1])
```

is there ANY way to preferably use the getSymbols to format one column with the dates as as.Date as above??  Help

Comment: This question belongs on stackoverflow.com

Comment: thank you Josh, I placed the question now on the aforementioned website as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a date column to an object returned by `getSymbols` or `get.hist.quote`. These function return matrices. Matrices can only store data of the same type, in this case the matrices contain `double` values (real numbers).

You can add a column of class `Date` to the objects if you transform them into a data frame:

For `getSymbols`:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('IBM', from = "2014-02-10")

IBM
#            IBM.Open IBM.High IBM.Low IBM.Close IBM.Volume IBM.Adjusted
# 2014-02-10   176.97   177.65  176.25    177.14    3540400       177.14
# 2014-02-11   176.81   180.39  176.80    179.70    4647300       179.70
# 2014-02-12   179.52   181.25  179.26    180.24    3983000       180.24
# 2014-02-13   178.22   182.36  177.86    181.84    4482000       181.84
# 2014-02-14   181.26   184.43  180.99    183.69    4659900       183.69

dat1 <- as.data.frame(IBM)
dat1$date <- time(IBM)

dat1
#            IBM.Open IBM.High IBM.Low IBM.Close IBM.Volume       date
# 2014-02-10   176.97   177.65  176.25    177.14    3540400 2014-02-10
# 2014-02-11   176.81   180.39  176.80    179.70    4647300 2014-02-11
# 2014-02-12   179.52   181.25  179.26    180.24    3983000 2014-02-12
# 2014-02-13   178.22   182.36  177.86    181.84    4482000 2014-02-13
# 2014-02-14   181.26   184.43  180.99    183.69    4659900 2014-02-14
```

The approach is similar for `get.hist.quote`:

```
library(tseries) 
res <- get.hist.quote(instrument = "ibm",  start = "2014-02-10")

res
#              Open   High    Low  Close
# 2014-02-10 176.97 177.65 176.25 177.14
# 2014-02-11 176.81 180.39 176.80 179.70
# 2014-02-12 179.52 181.25 179.26 180.24
# 2014-02-13 178.22 182.36 177.86 181.84
# 2014-02-14 181.26 184.43 180.99 183.69

dat2 <- as.data.frame(res)
dat2$date <- time(res)

dat2
#              Open   High    Low  Close       date
# 2014-02-10 176.97 177.65 176.25 177.14 2014-02-10
# 2014-02-11 176.81 180.39 176.80 179.70 2014-02-11
# 2014-02-12 179.52 181.25 179.26 180.24 2014-02-12
# 2014-02-13 178.22 182.36 177.86 181.84 2014-02-13
# 2014-02-14 181.26 184.43 180.99 183.69 2014-02-14
```

Comment: I just tried and on an individual basis it works but since my information is being stored in an environment (stockData), this approach is not being accepted. The error message is: Downloading  PBR Attempt:  1 / 5 
<simpleError in as.data.frame.default(stockData): cannot coerce class ""environment"" to a data.frame>

Comment: @EdgarSMartinez What is the name of the object in your environment?

Comment: the environment is called stockData

Comment: @EdgarSMartinez You can try `stockData2 <- eapply(stockData, as.data.frame)`. This will transform all objects in this environment into data frames. The result is stored in the list `stockData2`.